# Alamofire Deprication target Warning Silence

Tags: alamofire

How do I get rid of this warning?
My iOS Development Traget ist iOS 13
No Mac or TVOS Target added.

Updated to the new Version of Alamofire+

[Screenshot Alamofire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFwqc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to 5.6.4, which updated the package with the new deployment targets.